# spring mvc 3 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring-mvc

Error info: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestSpringWebApp/hello.htm]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am using annotation to map request to controller. 
controller code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello.htm")
public class HelloController  {    
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String now = (new Date()).toString();

        logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);

        return new ModelAndView("hello", "now", now);    
    }    
}
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
   <!-- <bean name="/hello.htm" class="com.kibboko.poprocks.web.HelloController"/>-->
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>

beans.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}"
          p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add @RequestMapping to the method, not to the class. If you add it to the class it will be applied as a prefix to all the methods mapping of this class, but you also have to map the methods of the class.

Comment: added @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) above method. still not working. Do I need to configure something like auto scanning package xyz so Spring can find controllers? Thanks a million.

Comment: @Bobo Do you have <mvc:annotation-driven /> as nickdos says?

Comment: Hi Javi, I did not have <mvc:annotation-driven /> in first place. But after adding it, it finally works. Thanks so much for your help and also nickdos'.

Answer (score 11):

You also need to add

`<mvc:annotation-driven />`

to your Dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You can have  @RequestMapping for class also, but every method also should have its own " @RequestMapping" please see below example.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
public class AppointmentsController {

    private final AppointmentBook appointmentBook;

    @Autowired
    public AppointmentsController(AppointmentBook appointmentBook) {
        this.appointmentBook = appointmentBook;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> get() {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForToday();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> getForDay(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day, Model model) {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForDay(day);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AppointmentForm getNewForm() {
        return new AppointmentForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@Valid AppointmentForm appointment, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "appointments/new";
        }
        appointmentBook.addAppointment(appointment);
        return "redirect:/appointments";
    }
}
```