# How to use MVC annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I think I've done everything right, but I still get 404's on all my pages (like /main/signup.htm). I'm kind of lost on what I could be missing here (the equivalent thing as xml configuration works, but I wanted to do this with annotations - this is an educational project and the rest of my team is even less familiar with spring and such than I am, so I thought doing at least some of the configuration in the java files would help ease them in).

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"> 


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd" >

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

MainController(imports omitted):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/default.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String defaultAfterLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(request.isUserInRole("ADMIN")) {
            return "redirect:/main/admin.htm";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/main/signup.htm";
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView signup() {
        return new ModelAndView("signup");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView admin() {
        return new ModelAndView("admin");
    }

}
```

some relevant part of catalina.out:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/hannes/.tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/login_proto-1.0.0.war
Jan 21, 2013 6:33:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springapp': initialization started
Jan 21, 2013 6:33:15 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springapp-servlet': startup date [Mon Jan 21 18:33:15 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 21, 2013 6:33:15 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]
Jan 21, 2013 6:33:15 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@499bb935: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
Jan 21, 2013 6:33:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springapp': initialization completed in 332 ms
Jan 21, 2013 6:33:22 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/login_proto-1.0.0/auth/login.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'
Jan 21, 2013 6:38:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/login_proto-1.0.0/main/default.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'
```

Comment: Is there anything defined in global pattern in file web.xml e.g.  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Comment: @ShashiBhushan The web.xml is literally what I posted here, I didn't edit anything.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305555/spring-mvc-3-no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri ..

Comment: @ShashiBhushan That doesn't seem to be relevant to my problem - the user there just forgot to add the RequestMapping to his methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.controller" />` tag to your `springapp-servlet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction, but now I get "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)"

Comment: did you added the spring-context.jar to your project?

Comment: Yes, I got spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar as well as spring-context-support-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar (even though I'm not sure what the latter is for, I just added it to be safe).

Comment: did you copy the springapp-servlet.xml that I posted? It had an error try with the updated version

Comment: You mean the extra quotation marks? No, I didn't copy it, I just added the xmlns:context and xsi:schemaLocation entries.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23108/discussion-between-cubic-and-jean-philippe-bond)